# Not getting correct output in linear regression

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

hi i have a doubt after (mean_squared_error=(y_test,y_pred)) this command I am not getting any output and also after lr_fit(x_train ,y_train) i am only getting linear regression

Answer (score 0):

```
# doesn't return anything
# it just fit the model
# https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html
lr.fit(x_train, y_train) 

# to get mean squared error, the correct syntax is
mae = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
print(mea)
```